# How to pass a module to spark submit that is used in UDFs

Tags: python, pyspark, spark-submit

I have a source code where a UDF is using `dill`. I have other packages used in my source code and all of them are listed in requirements.txt. So I am doing the following things but it says "module not found" for "dill"

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --target ./dependencies
cd dependencies
zip dependencies.zip .
cd ..

spark-submit --master yarn --jars example.jar --conf spark.executor.instances=10 --pyfiles dependencies.zip --name example_job example.py arg1 arg2
```

This gives the below error

```
No module named "dill"
```

I see we need to pass the egg files explicitly in the `--pyfiles` argument but where do I get the egg file for dill?

Answer (score 0):

I did it myself by downloading the source and generating the egg file out of it

```
pip download dill==0.3.1.1
tar -zxvf dill-0.3.1.1.tar.gz
cd dill-0.3.1.1
python setup.py bdist_egg
cp dist/*.egg ../
```

Any improvements for the above process are welcomed